# Use Dialogflow API to talk to bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

So I have a Dialogflow bot and I want to make it so that I can use it in the command line. I want to go on from there to turn it into a Discord bot, but I can't find out how to make it so that I can chat with it through the command line. I'm using node.js, help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow works best when you have a specific problem you have encountered that you're unable to solve, and you share the details of that problem so we can point you in the right direction. Showing us the code you're using, errors you've encountered, places where you get unexpected results, etc lets us clarify what you've been doing. Vague questions such as "help me" do not, in general, get useful answers that actually help. The more you show us that you've done - the better our chances are of being able to help.

Comment: @Prisoner I don't actually have any code......But I do have an idea. What I need to do is send a curl request to Dialogflow, but I the request headers and thingys are way too long and confusing and I don't know how to make them work.